# Doctrine update php models according to db

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I need to maintain a symfony 1.4 app , the app uses doctrine (1.2 I guess).
The problem is that people modified the databse without using doctrine.
To fix this i tried to update the doctrine models this way:

```
symfony doctrine:build-schema
symfony doctrine:build-model
```

Both does not show any errors but when I access the website everything fails due to db problems.

I got errors like 'unknown aliases'

Comment: try doing the updations manually.. sometimes the commands wont work as u want it to..

Comment: Unfortunately when this happens you need to manually check for differences between your schema and database. On the other hand "unknown alias" does not necessarily mean you have changes in the DB. It can be rather that your query addresses a relation alias which is not defined in the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following sriniwas advice everything went well , i guess ORM are not meant to do everything :(